# CURLOPT_CAINFO file extension (.pem or .crt)

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

What will be the certificate extension for below syntax : path_to_cacert (.pem or .crt)?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'path_to_cacert');
```

In some blog I have seen .pem and in blog its .crt.

I have EXPORT the certificate from Firefox browser >> page info >> view certificate >> EXPORT.

While exporting certificate, I have choose file type/format like below :

```
X.509 Certificate (PEM)
```

**Please note** : While exporting certificate like above, many blogs mentioning file as .crt, thought its exported as PEM

So, please someone clarify me about these difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libcurl, which does the underlying loading of the file with the help of the TLS library in use, doesn't care at all. You can use whatever extension you like.